# Devise authentication with STI sub classes and Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

So I am using STI to incorporate some roles into my users table. Right now I just have normal users and admins. I have installed Rails_admin and I need a way to authenticate admins but I am not sure how to do it safely.

Right now I have this code in my Application Controller

```
def authenticate_admin!(opts={})
  current_admin || redirect_to(?)
end

def current_admin
  current_user if current_user.is_a? Admin
end
```

In My rails_admin.rb file i have this

```
config.authenticate_with do
 authenticate_admin!
end
```

My current issue is that I cannot get the redirect_to to actually direct to anything. I keep getting errors. Also is a simple redirect if the user isn't an admin all I need? Is that best practice and most secure? Am I going in the right direction here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Would you consider using CanCan? Or is that off the table?

Comment: @StephSkardal  No that wouldn't be off the table actually. I was really only planning on having two subclasses so I didn't want to over complicate things. However if CanCan is the best solution to this problem, I can attempt to use it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect to a certain path if the user is not an admin, right? if so, then you could redirect_to root_path

Comment: @mohamed.magdy I figured out my redirect issue I had to use main_app.root_path or else it would error our on me. So I am using redirect_to main_app.root_url and that seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a couple things:

1) CanCan is pretty easy to use and worth the minor installation. Here's an example of what app/models/ability.rb might look like if you have two user instance methods is_admin? and is_reviewer?

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user && user.is_reviewer?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard
      cannot :read, [Class1, Class2, Class3]
      can :read, Class4
    end
    if user && user.is_admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Your RailsAdmin config would contain the following:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
  ...
end
```

And don't forget, you'll have to add cancan to your Gemfile to be installed as a dependency.

2) Next, and probably more valuable, is that you don't want to throw the redirect code in the authenticate method. Instead, you might want to add the following to ApplicationController:

```
rescue_from Acl9::AccessDenied do |exception|
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => { :success => false, :message => "You do not have access to do this action." }
    end
    format.html do
      flash[:error] = 'You do not have access to view this page.'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Or just:

```
rescue_from Acl9::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:error] = 'You do not have access to view this page.'
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: I actually decided to go the cancan way since I will have more than just admins. However since I have STI setup how do I make the ability.rb file work? Right now i have if user && user.is_a?(Admin) but that doesn't work

Comment: In my code, is_admin? and is_reviewer? are both custom methods for user instances. is_a? is a Ruby method for objects. Perhaps that's not working? Have you verified that it works in the console?

Comment: Ya I had to create the is_admin method in my user.rb model. Another thing i had to change from your code was `rescue_from Acl9::AccessDenied do |exception|` to `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|`. I got the rest of my issues solved from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527298/undefined-method-with-cancan-devise-and-sti-roles#comment12072535_9527298 Thanks!